# How to unlimit framerate?

Tags: c++, time, sfml, frame-rate

I am trying to completely unlimit the SFML framerate, so that as many frames will be displayed as possible. The reason for this is I want to loop through one section of code which calculates positions of objects in a physics simulation, and update the screen after perhaps 100 iterations.

I have done:

```
window.SetFramerateLimit(0);
window.UseVerticalSync(false);
```

The SFML documentation says this should set the frame rate to "infinity", but I still think it's stuck at about 60-ish.

Does anyone know how I can get more performance out of this?

Also once unlimited, I need to be able to do the equivalent of this in SFML, from SDL:

SDL.Delay(1000);

Is there a way of doing this? The SDL Delay is good because it frees CPU time for other processes.

Comment: this could be your monitor rather than SFML, some older monitors dont allow FPS past a certain point for performance reasons. How old is your monitor?

Comment: It's a Macbook Pro monitor, from a 13"3 Macbook 2011 model, running xubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By not setting a framerate limit, or setting it to zero, which is the default, the sfml window should display frames as fast as it is able too. Unfortunately, the problem appears to be with  the drivers, which are forcing vsync to be enabled. Because this is a Macbook Pro, with HD3000 graphics and an Intel driver, I don't know how to force vsync off.

There are other ways around this problem, such as using an if statement to decide whether to update the screen each loop. That is what I have done, although it is not an ideal solution.

In regards to SDL's delay function, SFML provides a `sf::Sleep()` function. This function is called with the argument of a `sf::Time` object, to which the user can set the number of microseconds, milliseconds and seconds to delay.

However note that this function does not "sleep" or "delay" for this exact amount of time - the OS comes back at "some time later which is at least after the requested sleep time". I do not understand fully how it works, or what "time resolution" you can expect to achieve with `sf::Sleep()` or `SDL_Delay()`.

Comment: @andreasm It isn't the same / appropriate

Answer (score 3):

Although you can de-/activate VSync with SFML, but it's not guaranteed that it will actually get activated, because the driver itself has the last word and they often provide an option to force VSync on or off. So I'd say you should take a look at your graphics driver's settings.

Then again I'm wondering what you actually want to achieve with the 'unlimited' frame-rate, because it will mostly just max out one core of your CPU, although the application is actually not doing anything. If you just want more CPU time for calculating stuff, then both methods (VSync & `setFramerateLimit()`) shouldn't block anything.

I strongly advise you to use SFML 2, because SFML 1.6 hasn't been maintained in over 2.5 years, has quite a few ugly bugs and lacks some very useful features (e.g. RenderTexture, VertexArray, ...).

Comment: Okay thanks, I downloaded SFML 2.0, but couldn't figure out how to set it up on xubuntu... There should have been a makefile or something, but there wasn't one... :(

The reason for unlimiting the framerate is that I will be able to maintain an arbitrary framerate without loosing cpu time for waiting for the next frame. The delay is to prevent problems with being able to move the window and other things.

Comment: The [official tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php) exist for a reason... SFML uses the build system CMake, which in turn will generate a makefile or a project file. For the frame-rate you should decouple the rendering and the physics, so you can run the physics at a fixed rate and display only when the image will also get shown.

Comment: Currently there is no physics running. There is an infinite loop which calls the window to display, hence I would have expected it to run at very much more than 60FPS, and would expect to see one CPU core with an execution close to 100%. This is not happening, and this is the problem.

Comment: I know what the problem is and I already gave you the solution in my response and linked you to the official tutorials, which is a must-read when getting started with SFML...

Comment: I don't see a solution, you are telling me to uncouple them, and I am telling you that is not the problem.

Comment: `Although you can de-/activate VSync with SFML, but it's not guaranteed that it will actually get activated, because the driver itself has the last word and they often provide an option to force VSync on or off. So I'd say you should take a look at your graphics driver's settings.`

Comment: Do you know how I go about this in Linux?

Comment: No since every Linux distro handles things a bit different. Most likely you'll have to edit some config files and less likely you could find a GUI that does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on the framerate issue. According to the documentation, that would work. One thing I would try is removing (or commenting out) one statement at a time, see if it helps, OR both: vertical since is supposed to be off defaultly, and I feel like the framerate would default to infinity, but I may be wrong. Also, it might be that the framerate is infinite, but the calculations simply just take enough time that it does do it ~60 fps. Lastly, perhaps it is a limit of the monitor, as suggested above.

On the delay, I believe you are thinking of a sleep function - make the current thread pause for a certain amount of time. I know in SFML 2, this is sf::sleep(sf::Time), where  the time could be derived by, for example: sf::seconds(float t), sf::milliseconds, etc. They return a Time object. In SFML 1.6, it is sf::Sleep(float seconds).

Also, I don't know if this fixes it, but I think SFML has had some problems on the Apple side, so mabye  , assuming you are using 1.6 or less, version 2 fixed the problem. Version 2 is now out as... well, you don't have to compile it yourself. I think it fixed other things, perhaps this was an issue before.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will apt-get the new version or something and see if it makes a difference.

Also there is no code running to slow it down, it should just loop forever in a while loop. The statement which slows the program down to 60FPS is window.Display(); which is the SFML method to update the screen.

Comment: In that case, it is probably something else. I was just wondering if your physics simulations might have slowed it down. In the case, I am guessing it is the monitor/vsync.